# Symfony2 TreeBuilder configuration - validate against a set value

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1

I have the following configuration for a bundle:

```
    $supportedAdapters = array('curl', 'socket');

    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('example_bundle');
    $rootNode
            ->children()
            ->scalarNode('username')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->scalarNode('password')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
            ->scalarNode('adapter')
                ->validate()
                    ->ifNotInArray($supportedAdapters)
                    ->thenInvalid('The adapter %s is not supported. Please choose one of '.json_encode($supportedAdapters))
                ->end()
                ->cannotBeOverwritten()
                ->isRequired()
                ->cannotBeEmpty()
            ->end()
            // allow the use of a proxy for cURL requests
            ->arrayNode('proxy')
                ->children()
                    ->scalarNode('host')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('port')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                    ->scalarNode('username')->defaultValue(null)->end()
                    ->scalarNode('password')->defaultValue(null)->end()
                ->end()
            ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
```

We support two adapters: `curl` and `socket`.

We only support using a proxy for `curl` requests. In the configuration I want to check that if the proxy is set and the adapter is not curl, then throw an error informing the user that "We only support the curl adapter for use with a  proxy". Is there a way to get a set value ( in our case adapter) and check it's value and validate against it?

Pseudo code:

```
IF PROXY IS SET AND ADAPTER IS NOT EQUAL TO CURL THEN:
 THROW ERROR ("We don't support the use of a proxy with the socket adapter");
END IF;
```

I hope this makes sense. I've read all of the documentation and API docs but, alas, I can't seen an option to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Worked it out:

```
    $supportedAdapters = array('curl', 'socket');

    $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
    $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('example_bundle');
    $rootNode
            ->validate()
                ->ifTrue(function($v){ return isset($v['proxy']) && 'curl' !== $v['adapter'];})
                ->thenInvalid('Proxy support is only available to the curl adapter.')
            ->end()
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('username')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                ->scalarNode('password')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                ->scalarNode('adapter')
                    ->validate()
                        ->ifNotInArray($supportedAdapters)
                        ->thenInvalid('The adapter %s is not supported. Please choose one of '.json_encode($supportedAdapters))
                    ->end()
                    ->cannotBeOverwritten()
                    ->isRequired()
                    ->cannotBeEmpty()
                ->end()
                // allow the use of a proxy for cURL requests
                ->arrayNode('proxy')
                    ->children()
                        ->scalarNode('host')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                        ->scalarNode('port')->isRequired()->cannotBeEmpty()->end()
                        ->scalarNode('username')->defaultValue(null)->end()
                        ->scalarNode('password')->defaultValue(null)->end()
                    ->end()
            ->end();

    return $treeBuilder;
```

:-)